# Site cannot be installed: Page has no manifest <link> URL

Tags: google-chrome, console.log

[image]

On **Chrome** Console it show this error message

I can avoid this by adding manifest link
but I don't want to add on each page/layout

Is there any other way to avoid this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Avoid this error 
I have added below line in layout page

`<link rel="manifest" href="~/manifest.json">`

I'm posting this if it's can help anyone.

Answer (score 5):

Add the manifest to your page Finally, we need to add a link to the manifest in the page. Open **work/index.html**. Add the following right before the closing `</head>` tag:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="~/manifest.json">
```

Create **work** name mainfest like below eg.

```
{
  "short_name": "",
  "name": "",
  "icons": [
  {
    "src":"",
    "sizes": "",
    "type": ""
  }
 ],
 "start_url": "",
 "background_color": "",
 "Theme_color": "",
 "display": ""
}
```

For more detail reference below Link :
[Manifest](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/add-to-home-screen/#3)

Comment: In My given answer I have created Work name Mainfest

Comment: For more detail pls refer attached link. It will help to you.

Comment: Ohk... Than go into that folder and find index.html file and Add the following right before the closing </head> tag: 
<link rel="manifest" href="~/manifest.json">

Comment: what do you mean by  "*work* name"? There is no reference to it in your manifest

Comment: The link provided provides 404. Here is the link for additional information on web app manifests. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest